# Triggering after an update or delete on a FK constraint between 2 tables in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have the following tables:

```
create table emp_test_lucian as select employee_id,last_name,first_name,department_id from employees;
ALTER TABLE emp_test_lucian
ADD PRIMARY KEY (employee_id);

create table dept_test_lucian as select department_id,department_name from departments_copy;
ALTER TABLE dept_test_lucian
ADD PRIMARY KEY (department_id);
```

On this tables I want to perform different operations for example: If a department gets deleted (from dept_test_lucian) I will delete all the rows in emp_test_lucian that have that department id with a trigger. This works fine when no fk between the 2 is declared with the following code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER triger5
 BEFORE UPDATE or DELETE on dept_test_lucian
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF DELETING then
  delete 
  from emp_test_lucian
  where department_id = :OLD.department_id;
 else if UPDATING('department_id') then
  UPDATE emp_test_lucian
  set department_id = :NEW.department_id
  where department_id = :OLD.department_id;
 END IF;
END IF;
END;
/
```

What can I add to the code above to work even if I have a fk between the 2 tables like so:

```
ALTER TABLE emp_test_lucian
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_dep_id FOREIGN KEY(department_id) REFERENCES dept_test_lucian(department_id);

the current code returns :
Error report:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (C##LABORATOR.SYS_C009994) violated
ORA-06512: at line 2
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make clear what table is the 'parent' and what table is the 'child'.

In your example: 
- Parent: dept_test_lucian 
- Child: emp_test_lucian

Lets call 'dept_test_lucian': TableA 
Lets call 'emp_test_lucian': TableB

I come to this conclusion since there is a CONSTRAINT on  TableB.department_id" that can only have a value that exists 
in "TableA.department_id"

The error message tells you that there is a 'primary key being vialated'. 
Primary keys on you tables are: 
- "TableA.employee_id" 
- "TableB.department_id"

Apparently you are trying to insert a value in one of these columns where that value already exists in. 
If '1' is already existing in "TableA.employee_id" you would get such an error.

What I also see in your trigger is: 
You have a BEFORE UPDATE Trigger.

So the Trigger looks if there is an UPDATE comming on "TableA" (Parent). 
Then you try to UPDATE "TableB" (child) first. 
This could be tricky, since "TableB.department_id" can only have values that exist in "TableA.department_id". 
If the new UPDATE value doesn't exist in "TableA.department_id", you can not UPDATE that value in "TableB.department_id"

Comment: You mixed up TableA.department_id and TableB.employee_id but that's not the point . I get the point you are trying to make. Indeed After is the solution here :D

Comment: hypothetically speaking if that foreign key had ON DELETE NULL . I guess i couldn't delete in that trigger the rows from emp_test_lucian could i ? (because that table would be used)  even with AFTER there. What could I do to trigger the deletion of the NULL rows?

Comment: I think I now have a clear view of what you are trying? So you ask "What could I do to trigger the deletion of the NULL rows?" You can also put the trigger on the table to activate only at certain rows. Is that what you meen?

Comment: My initial question was just what you answered it is good. My extra question if you have the time to answer is what if the key that we discussed about above would be declared with also the ON DELETE NULL. This would make all the department_id's of the department that is deleted null in emp_test_lucian . After that happens i want to delete the rows that have the department_id null :D (i could put ON DELETE CASCADE but no, my task is with NULL not with CASCADE) . So i guess you understood my 2nd question :D Even with the AFTER keyword the trigger says emp_test_lucian is mutating in the ex above

Comment: I think what you want you can not do. Because of "department_id". In the parent table "dept_test_lucian" you have a PRIMARY KEY on "department_id". That means that you need at least one value here. You need to fill in something. And since the child table can only have the values that exist in the parents "department_id". The child cannot use the  NULL value eather.

Comment: i delete it from dept_test_lucian and because it's set ON DELETE NULL it will make the department_id from emp_test_lucian NULL won't it ? . And then i want to delete the null rows from emp_test_lucian with the trigger

Comment: You CONSTRAINT "fk_dep_id" demands the value in "emp_test_lucian .department_id" to be a value that exists in "dept_test_lucian.department_id". Since "dept_test_lucian.department_id" has this column also as a PRIMARY KEY, "dept_test_lucian.department_id" can not have NULL. So "emp_test_lucian .department_id" can not be NULL eather.

Comment: If "dept_test_lucian.department_id" would not be be PRIMARY KEY, then it would be possible to have a NULL in "emp_test_lucian .department_id"

Comment: You should first delete the 'child' records and then the 'parent' records.

Comment: when I put on delete SET NULL it will delete the department_id from dept_test_lucian and it will set null in emp_test_lucian.department_id, IF I delete something. I did some research on the question i had and it seems the only way to do what i am trying to is by using a view and trying to delete on that :D And so I did . thank you very very much for you interest , sorry to have bothered you so much!